# RxJava2 TestObserver class - where is getOnNextEvent similar to TestSubscriber class?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I am searching for a way to get the values returned from onNext in a subscriber so i can verify the results. TestSubscriber had a nice method called [getOnNextEvent](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestSubscriber.html#getOnNextEvents()) but when i use [TestObserver](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observers/TestObserver.html) i dont see a method like this i can use so that i can get the results to check it ? There all deprecated and when i check in the IDE there not even showing up.

Here is what i want to test:

```
`@Test
   public void buildUseCaseObservable(){

TestObserver subscriber = TestObserver.create();
standardLoginUsecase.buildUseCaseObservable().subscribe(subscriber);

      subscriber.assertNoErrors();
      subscriber.assertSubscribed();
      subscriber.assertComplete();
      //i would like to test the actual onNext results also , but how ?
  }`
```

**UPDATE**:
I FOUND  a getEvents method but its deprecated.  i dont see any alternative though.

Comment: See [values()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/observers/BaseTestConsumer.html#values()).

Comment: How were you looking for the methods? You are supposed to find these methods when using your IDE's content assist/intellisense feature. We get quite a lot of such reports and we are inclined to provide better discoverability as much as possible, but the only distinctive factor so far was the use of a particular IDE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
TestObserver<List<User>> testObserver = new TestObserver<>();
testObserver.values();
```

Use values method to test the onNext Items